# How to pass a model to a strongly typed partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that handles a certain model.
How can I pass it to the partial view from a view that has no references for that model?

My partial view has:

```
@model MyNS.Models.NewsComment
```

How can I call from:

```
@Html.Partial("CommentForm", Model.NewsComments.SingleOrDefault())  //does not work
```

Comment: What sort of errors (if any) are you getting?

Comment: I get this error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyNS.Models.News', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyNS.Models.NewsComment" ; i call from the News model but i need to insert a NewsComment item from the partial view

Comment: It sounds like your "NewsComments" property is typed as "News" and not "NewsComment". Can you check this and/or post the code for the model in your main view (the class that has the NewComments property)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have no reference it on your view to the model, you can do the following one :

```
  @{
      var repo = new Models.MyRepo();
      var partialModel = repo.GetAll();
  }

  @Html.Partial("CommentForm", partialModel)
```

But this is totally against the ASP.NET MVC's `Seperation of Concerns` theory.

What I would do is to pass it to the view as model (event if I won't use it inside my view) and pass it to the Partial from my view. That way you handle the data access from your controller which would be the better approach.

**UPDATE**

I have just seen you comment about the error. On this case what you would do is as follows for a better approach (the first case I have shown above will also work for this):

Create a ViewModel as follows :

```
public class MyViewModel { 

    public MyNS.Models.News News {get; set;}
    public MyNS.Models.NewsComment NewsComment {get; set;}

}
```

And then pass it your view as follows :

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
viewModel.News = repo.GetNews();
viewModel.NewsComment = repo.GetNewsComment();

retun View(viewModel);
```

then work on it on your view as follows :

```
@Html.Partial("CommentForm", Model.NewsComment)
```

Comment: Your code assumes that news is a seperate entity entirely unrelated to newscomment. From his code its easy to see that NewsComment is a navigational property of News (most likely a db relationship exists)

Comment: then he is passing completely wrong model. His partial is typed to `MyNS.Models.NewsComment` but he is passing a model typeof `MyNS.Models.News`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the NewsComments property in your model is of type `IEnumerable<News>` while it should be `IEnumerable<NewsComment>` Probably you have used a LINQ query to populate the model's NewsComments property with a faulty select statement.